# Is it css or php that make every word in one line in my code?

Tags: css

I want the phrase to be in middle in "one line"

css code:

```
#paypal-con {
    padding-top: 1em;
}
#paypal-con > div {
    float: right;
}
#paypal-con form {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 15px 0 -10px;
}
```

php code:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" id="paypal-con"><align="left">
        <div>
            Please choose your plan before sign up:<br><center>
```

Please check below screenshot for reference.
[image]

Comment: Sir, that's not php code, that's HTML. The cause of that styling issue is because of CSS but I hate front end and I have no idea what the solution is. Possibly something to do with the `margin:`

Comment: Heads up, `<center>` is a deprecated tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center & `align` is not a tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/align

Comment: Also, if you are using a framework like Bootstrap, you most likely have helper-classes to help you align content which you should be taking advantage of.

Comment: use col-md-12 instead of col-md-3 col-md-offset-2

Comment: It is part of big php code, anyway, why every word on one line..

Comment: add all relevant code to replicate the issue

Comment: You are right it is because of "margin:" thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change this.....

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" id="paypal-con"><align="left">
    <div>
        Please choose your plan before sign up:<br><center>
```

To

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-2" id="paypal-con" align="center">        
        Please choose your plan before sign up:
</div>
```